# Is there a way to format completion tooltips in Visual Studio?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, intellisense, mef

I write a package for VS2015 which provides completion suggestions. To show completion popups I use `Microsoft.VisualStudio.Language.Intellisense.Completion` class. Now I need to format text in completion tooltips (some parts of tooltip text should look highlighted). Unfortunately HTML-tags don't help here. Is there a way to format tooltip text?

Comment: Hi ababo, does your issue is solved or not? If not, you can update your current issue in here.

Comment: Actually not, I still didn't find a way to highlight words in completion tooltips.

Answer (score 0):

> Unfortunately HTML-tags don't help here. Is there a way to format tooltip text?

Microsoft.VisualStudio.Language.Intellisense.Completion does not support HTML-tags and other font formatter.

You can use different iconSource Distinguish different contents. like this:

```
new Completion(str, str, str, new BitmapImage(new Uri("youURL/xml.gif", UriKind.Absolute)), null)
```

[image]